# why we need function $f$ is decreasing for $f'(x)\ge c_1 f^2(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If we know a decreasing function $f(x)$ satisfies that
$$f'(x)\ge c_1 f^2(x)$$

Let $g(x)=1/f(x)$, then
$$g'(x)\le -c_1$$

My question is that why does the reciprocal of $f$ exist?

Comment: In our daily life, we don't need that $f$ is decreasing, nor do we need that $f'(x)\ge c_1f^2(x)$. What is the ultimate goal? What motivates the inequality?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen If we want the existence of the inverse function $f^{-1}$, we need the monotonicity of $f$, right?

Comment: That indeed. But if your goal is to show that $(f^{-1})'\ge c_1$, why not formulate that in terms of $f'$ itself?

Comment: Also, I must be missing something (sorry). How do you get the thing after "then" here? (and is it really $f^{-1}$ you want, not $1/f$?)

Comment: @ClementC. Yes I mean $1/f$.

Comment: @Hermi Then careful -- this is not a standard way to refer to it ($f^{-1}$ is typically the inverse function, you want the reciprocal $1/f$). Also, you should get $g'(x) \leq -c_1$.